# python ipaddress()reverse_pointer equivalent for 3.4

Tags: python, dns, ip, ipv6

I am trying to get the reverse IPv6 arpa from a valid IPv6 address but the feature I would like to use is only available in Python3.5 and FreeBSD ports is still on Python3.4

```
In [1]: import ipaddress
In [3]: ipaddress.ip_address("2001:db8::1").reverse_pointer

AttributeError: 'IPv6Address' object has no attribute 'reverse_pointer'
```

What is the Python3.4 equivalent to get the reverse IPv6 arpa?

[ipaddress 3.5 manual page](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/ipaddress.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply download the source code of Python 3.5 and copy-past the function you need,

```
def _reverse_pointer(self):
    """Return the reverse DNS pointer name for the IPv6 address.

    This implements the method described in RFC3596 2.5.

    """
    reverse_chars = self.exploded[::-1].replace(':', '')
    return '.'.join(reverse_chars) + '.ip6.arpa'
```

Which can be used as follows,

```
In [1]: import ipaddress
In [2]: ip_addr = ipaddress.ip_address("2001:db8::1")
In [3]: _reverse_pointer(ip_addr)
Out[3]: '1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.8.b.d.0.1.0.0.2.ip6.arpa'
```